# ASP.NET Session variable data lost randomly for random users

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables, session-state, iis-10

I have a web application created using .Net Framework 4.6.1. Recently, I started getting complaints from users that they were redirected to the login page. It only happens when session data is not found. I check for the user's session variable in Master page. Interestingly, it happens with only a few users randomly and no one can reproduce the issue. The web application is hosted on Windows Server 2016 using IIS 10. I use "InProc" session state and the setting I use in web.config is below.

```
<httpCookies sameSite="Strict" httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" maxRequestLength="30720" requestValidationMode="4.0" executionTimeout="300" enableVersionHeader="false"/>
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="240" cookieSameSite="Strict" cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId"/>
```

I don't use a load-balancer and have set worker process to 1. I checked logs in EventViewer and didn't find any application level exceptions. There aren't any application pool recycles during the random logout time.

Has anyone had similar issues? What could be wrong in the configuration file? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just turn on and use and adopt SQL server based sessions, and all your issues, and troubles in life will go away. The simple matter is just about any un-handled error can trigger a app-pool restart, and that means your session is lost. Turn on SQL server based session management, and even a re-start of the app pools, or in fact a restart of IIS will not effect users - their sessions will remain intact.  We had nothing but issues and troubles - adopting SQL server session based management fixed all of our woe's

Comment: 240 is not in seconds but in minutes. There is no pool recycling during day time. I am not worry about that,

Comment: Well, any un-handled error can blow out session and trigger a app pool restart. So, unless you are 100% sure no errors trigger in your code, you can't assume session() will remain intact.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Currently, I use Session_End event to clean up few items in database. How can I achieve it with StateServer or SQL Server based session ? This event is only available for "InProc" session state.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal If app pool gets restarted due to error, then all users should have lost their sessions. Why few users (2% of total) are affected ?

Comment: Don't know - maybe there not a lot of users on the site at that point in time, or code that sets session values runs again, or before the loss. I mean, if users don't logout, or while on your site close their laptop lid, or from that same page start shopping on Amazon, then session end will not likely trigger in any timely kind of way, or even at all. So, if this is super rare, then you have to trap and log errors on the site, and try to eliminate that error in question - or adopt SQL server based sessions.  Maybe it is a app-pool recycle occurring while user is logged on - and hence rare.